# Get session account user name in Windows command/batch running as administrator

Tags: windows, cmd, administrator

**Facts**

On a non admin Windows account:

Execute in a command prompt: `echo %username%`
It will display the current user name.

Execute in a command prompt as administrator: `echo %username%`
It will display the admin user name.

**Question**

How to get the current user name in a program/script running as administrator ?

---

**A strange behavior:**

In a command prompt running as administrator:

- `explorer %appdata%` will open an explorer window in the AppData of the administrator.
- `start %appdata%` will open an explorer windows in the AppData of the current user.

Comment: seems like running process as admin is always under the user:administrator. <br/>When you are doing start %appdata% you're opening a new process under a different user

Comment: If you ``start`` a bat file: ``echo %appdata%`` it displays the administrator appdata directory too...

Comment: Thx @HarryJohnston, it's not a real duplicate because it requires C++.
But that will help me.

Comment: My reasoning was that the question says "in a program/script".  The proposed duplicate shows you how to do it in a program.  (And there is no way to do it in a script, other than by running a program to do it for you.)